# Gitlab CI Runner get stuck, ssh not responding

Tags: gradle, amazon-ec2, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have created a gitlab runner in an aws EC2 instance, and i have the following ci script:

```
stages:
- unit_test
- cleanup_build_when_fail
- deploy_to_sit

unit_test:
  stage: unit_test
  script:
  - export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-5.0/bin
  - export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test
  - gradle clean test
  - echo "unit_test completed!"
  when: always

 ... with other scripts
```

Sometimes, the unit_test stage completed correctly within 1 minute.

But sometimes it gets stuck until timeout, when it gets stuck, the ec2 instance is not even responding. I have to restart the ec2 instance so that i can connect to it again. Here is the output when it get stuck:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-5.0/bin
$ export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test
$ gradle clean test
> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources
> Task :testClasses
```

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this, please help.

*UPDATE*: the task does not timeout, here is what i saw from gitlab

```
Duration: 16 minutes 58 seconds
Timeout: 15m (from project)
```

Comment: What are you tests? Don't you have any HTTP calls or other operations that can block / stuck in them?

Comment: the test starts a spring boot application and performed crud operation to a testing database. if the HTTP calls blocked the CI, I think the default timeout should disconnect the connection. The test can get stuck for more than an hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got my solution, it was the OOM.

The solution is to set maximum memory limit to your build, eg: nodejs(yarn) or spring (gradle)